# Backup data to NAS and Cloud

Tags: backup, nas, cloud-storage, incremental-backup, synology-diskstation

I have a local workstation (Windows Server) and I want to backup 2 of its data drives nightly for a total of about 2.5TB. I also have a NAS (DS218+) connected to the network with 2 HDDs in RAID.

I want to have a local backup in case my workstation fails and also a cloud backup to avoid having the data all at the same location.

My plan is to first backup the drives to the NAS and then backup the NAS to the cloud.

My first instinct is to use a backup software on my Windows workstation itself to push the data to the NAS and then use another software on the NAS to push the data to the cloud. A full backup copy would take about 6 hours for 2.5 TB of data, so I would probably want to do incremental backups after the initial one, especially for the one on the cloud.

Does my plan make sense? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: How are you verifying what was written to the NAS matches the source files? How are you verifying what's on the cloud matches what's in the source files?

Comment: These are good questions! I assume that if the scheduled task finished, the files match... What would be a better alternative?

Comment: Write a script with Crsync  https://itefix.net/cwrsync

Comment: That does what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Synology has cloud backup applications in its DSM, Cloud Backup, for instance.

As the network backup is slow, you better have to

- locally backup your datas at H hour.
- Snapshot your backup on synology at H-1 hour
- Cloud backup yesterday’s backup each night.

With this kind of delayed backup, you may avoid the “uncompleted” risk.

It may even be better if you delegate a iSCSI share on your windows server, and find a way to save only changes on it, thru a rsync for instance. If you backup a whole TAR, it will maximize the differences between two day, even if only a few files have changed on the source server.